# Can't delete e-mails from Mail app

Tags: macos, email

I have a mail account with lot of e-mails stored on server (around 100 thousand). I would like to clean it using Mail app and delete all unnecessary messages. But so far no luck

Store deleted e-mails on server is UNCHECKED.
Move deleted messages to Trash is UNCHECKED.

When I delete the messages they seem to disappear, but they appear again when I click on a different mailbox and back to the current one or when I restart the Mail app.

I have tried deleting all content of ~/Library/Mail/V2 folder and reimport all e-mails but it didn't help.

I have also tried to check the Move deleted messages to Trash, but then I am getting following error when exiting the Mail app:

[image: screenshot]

Also the Mail app seems to freeze when I try to exit. Or is it trying to delete the e-mails? I have tried to leave it open some hours but it didn't help neither.

Any suggestions?

The account is connected using IMAP, I am using OS X 10.8.2 (had the same problem at 10.8.1).

Comment: I'd suggest moving the deleted messages to Trash in small chunks (for example, ~500 messages at a time). My experience is that Mail has trouble performing operations on large amounts of data.

Comment: @jaume That would take insanely long time. It's sad that none e-mail client that I've tried does not support queue for deleting messages.

Comment: I understand. Does your mail provider offer webmail? You could give it a try if it had a comfortable interface for deleting folders...

Comment: do the logs say anything? have you performed a permissions check?

Comment: @jaume: I am afraid that no webmail is available :-(

Comment: @Agos: Persmissons are not the problem I guess. Messages are deleted, but very slowly. Which logs do you mean?

Comment: Too bad there's no webmail available. It seems you have to go through the painful process of deleting messages in small chunks...

Comment: @PetrPeller I'd take a look in console.app to see if anything suspicious gets written at mail.app startup, or when you try the operation